# Why is MyBatis returning a Collection of null objects?

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I have the following basic models:

```
public class Sandbox {
    private String firstName;
    private Integer age;
    private List<Split> split;
}

public class Split {
    private Integer sandboxId;
}
```

My SandboxMapper is configured as below:

```
<resultMap id="SandboxMap" type="Sandbox">
    <id property="firstName" column="FIRSTNAME"/>
    <result property="age" column="AGE"/>
    <collection property="split" javaType="list" ofType="Split" column="AGE" select="selectSplit">
        <id property="sandboxId" column="SANDBOX_ID"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>

<select id="selectSandbox" resultMap="SandboxMap">
    SELECT * FROM SANDBOX
    WHERE AGE=#{age}
</select>

<select id="selectSplit" parameterType="int" resultType="com.scibor.Split">
    SELECT * FROM SPLIT
    WHERE Split.SANDBOX_ID=#{age}
</select>
```

And I have in my Database some entries such that there is a Sandbox with Age 14 and there are a few Splits whose SANDBOX_ID is 14. There are no imposed constraints on any of the columns because it was not specified in the documentation that I had to do so, i.e. these are all simple data types, `NUMBER` and `VARCHAR` no notion of `PRIMARY KEY`, `NOT NULL` etc.

Within my code I then invoke:

```
Sandbox sandbox = session.selectOne("Sandbox.selectSandbox", 14);
```

This returns a `Sandbox` object whose `Name` and `Age` fields are properly set, however, the array associated with `splits` it's just an array of nulls. If I was to guarantee uniqueness and change `collection` to `association`, it would be the same thing, `split` would just be `null`.

I've been staring at this for some time and I have tried all sorts of values for `column` in `collection` tag, as well as various variants of the `selectSplit` entry, but none of them work, they always return a null value for `split`. More annoyingly, no exceptions are thrown so it seems that all of the SQL queries being generated are in fact valid (most likely the last `#{age}` is itself `null`).

Can someone please explain how I can retrieve an instance of `Sandbox` with a `List<Split>` populated using MyBatis? The documentation is helpful but I have followed the examples, I think exactly, yet I am still not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the difficulty was in this line:

```
<select id="selectSplit" parameterType="int" resultType="com.scibor.Split">
```

One of the things I had taken for granted was that the property names in Split do not match up with the names of the columns for the associated table. So instead of using a `resultType`, I had to create the following:

```
<resultMap id="SplitMap" type="Split">
    <id column="SANDBOX_ID" property="sandboxId"/>
</resultMap>
```

This resolved the issue.